# How to install specific library using "pip" command

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install certain library in `Visual Studio Code` terminal using `pip install *library*` command and I am getting error:

> pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable    program. Check the spelling of
>   the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
>   and try again.

I tried with `pip3` command as well and got same message. I am executing python files with `py -3` command.

Comment: Which message by pip3?

Comment: pip3 : The term 'pip3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path    
is correct and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install library like this
python -m pip install numpy

Comment: got this "python.exe: No module named install" after I tried next command: py -3 -m install "library"